# why is not writing over the two diferent files?

Tags: node.js, fs

Where is the problem?
I can not write into the files in the right order.

File "gestorFicheros.js"

```
// open log file
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {

    fichero: null,
    dia_actual: null,
    nombre: null,
    path: null,

    crearFichero: function(path, nombre){
        this.fichero = fs.createWriteStream(path + "/" + nombre, {flags: 'a'});
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.path = path;

        this.fichero.on('error', function(e) { 
            console.log("Error:" + e);
            process.exit(1);
        });

        return(this);
    },

    escribe: function(datos){
        this.fichero.write(datos + "\r\n");
    }
};
```

File "test.js"

```
var ficheros = require('./gestorFicheros.js');

var a = ficheros.crearFichero("./registros", "todas.txt", {flags: 'a'});;
var b = ficheros.crearFichero("./registros", "no-repetidas.txt", {flags: 'a'});;

a.escribe("hola");
b.escribe("adios");
a.escribe("hola");
```

Results:

no-repetidas.txt

```
hola
adios
hola
```

todas.txt

Expected Results:

no-repetidas.txt

```
adios
```

todas.txt

```
hola
hola
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing `return(this);`

You are modifying the same object. Not returning a new instance, so the last sentence that modifies the object is the one that sets the file name.